# Cookie management in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cookies

I want to add some stuff to cookie in ASP.net MVC.

What is best way to handle all stuff in a cookie or more cookie.

Any good way to handle cookie in asp.net mvc?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here's an example:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult CreateCookie()
    {
        var cookie = new HttpCookie("cookie_name", "some value");
        Response.AppendCookie(cookie);
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult ReadCookie()
    {
        var cookie = Request.Cookies["cookie_name"];
        if (cookie != null)
        {
            string value = cookie.Value;
        }
        return View();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this one, may be helpful

http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2008/07/08/asp-net-mvc-tip-15-pass-browser-cookies-and-server-variables-as-action-parameters.aspx