# How do I add a cookie for every visitor to my asp.net MVC site?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm experimenting with an ASP.NET MVC 3 site, using razor as the view-engine. I need to assign a cookie to every visitor of my site. What would be the best place/way to do this?
Please elaborate, because I'm very new at ASP.NET.

Comment: looks like a possible dup, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3147323/cookie-management-in-mvc

Comment: Hi Jon, nope; I know how to add a cookie, the core question is how/where to do that for every visitor.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are 3 ways to implement it without breaking mvc pattern:

1 - Base controller class with specified behaviour at `OnActionExecuting` / `OnActionExecuted` / `OnResultExecuting` method (if this behavior is **necessary** across the entire web site)

2 - Create action filter with specified behaviour at `OnActionExecuting` / `OnActionExecuted` / `OnResultExecuting` methods:

```
public class MyCookieSettingFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute 
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie(name, value));
    }
}
```

and

assign filter attribute to some controllers/actions (if this behavior is **not necessary** for all web site), for example

```
[MyCookieSettingFilter]
public class MyHomeController : Controller
{
}
```

or

```
public class MyAccountController : Controller
{
    [MyCookieSettingFilter]
    public ActionResult Login()
    {
    }
}
```

3 - Create action filter with specified behaviour at `OnActionExecuting` / `OnActionExecuted` / `OnResultExecuting` methods and register it at `global.asax` - it will work for all actions of all controllers (if this behavior is **necessary** for all web site)

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{
   filters.Add(new MyCookieSettingFilterAttribute());
}
```

I don't recommend to use Base Controller way, because it less extensible than Global Filter way. Use different global filters for providing different independent global behaviors.

Comment: Ah, clear, so the filters allow for more finegrained control over where you want to apply the cookie. I will have to think about whether or not we need a cookie set on every page for every user or not... Thanks for the detailed explanation.

Comment: Yes, using filter attributes gives you more finegrained control. You can add parameters to attribute constructor (for example MyCookiesAddingAttribute(string name) ), apply for controller [MyCookiesAdding("A")] and override for some action [MyCookiesAdding("B")]. It's very powerful mechanism.

Comment: Thanks for that example Evgeny, I wasn't aware of these filters.

Comment: Rico, it looks like you also have the option to make the filter global by adding it to the global.asax - http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2010/08/15/asp-net-mvc-3-global-action-filters.aspx

Answer (score 4):

This would work regardless of what page the user first comes in at.
You could inherit your controllers with a base controller and then add some information to the OnActionExecuting method

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        HttpCookie myCookie = Request.Cookies[keyOfSomeKind];

        if (myCookie == null)
        {
            HttpCookie newCookie
                = new HttpCookie(keyOfSomeKindy, "Some message");
            newCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(3);
            current.Response.Cookies.Add(newCookie);
        }

        base.OnActionExecuting(context);
    }
}
```

Comment: This would be better suited as an action filter than as a base controller IMO.

Comment: Chris, can you elaborate? Because this would be an ideal solution for me, because I already have a basecontroller class in my code at the moment.. I'm curious what the advantages of an action filter would be.

Comment: @Rico Suave it would be better as an action filter because it makes your usage more loosely coupled. It is far more simple to choose to decorate or not decorate controllers and actions than it is to add and undo base controllers. In MVC Base controllers tend to be (or lead to) code smell.

Comment: And an example of why Base controllers can lead to code smell, take this code above. Suppose you have a controller where for 1 specific action you absolutely CAN'T have that cookie created. At this point you have no recourse other than to hack the base controller to support your edge case, or to remove the action from the original controller and create a new controller to serve that single action that doesn't depend on that base controller.

Answer (score 1):

You already have session and the session cookie.

But if you need to write a specific value to a cookie you have access to the response stream from the controller

`this.Response.Cookies.Add();` inside the controller (this isn't required)

Comment: Thanks for the response Chris, the reason I'm not using the session cookie is that this website shares a database with a legacy (classic) asp site. In that site we used a UUID cookie to link to per-user data stored in the database. This allows us to maintain state for a user even between server reboots or when a user logs off and logs on again.

Comment: @Rico Suave just remember to keep concerns about session hijacking from cookie stealing. And make sure you use cookies that are HttpOnly and to evaluate whether you would want to go SSL only too.

Answer (score 1):

Setting a cookie should be done in your controller. You can set a cookie like so:

```
Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie(cookieName, cookieValue));
```

If you need to get the value in your view, the best way would be to fetch it in your controller and stick it in a view model or viewstate:

```
var cookie = Response.Cookies[cookieName];
ViewData["CookieInfo"] = cookie.Value;
```

And in your view:

```
@ViewData["CookieInfo"]
```

Comment: Cookies get added to the response, not request. They are read from the request. I'm about 97% certain ASP.NET won't try to help you and put the cookie in the response for you if you do this.