# Cookie in asp.net mvc not setting

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, cookies

I am experiencing strange situation. The set cookie is persisted only when the string is hard coded.

```
public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
{
    if (filterContext.HttpContext.Items["Theam"] != null)
    {
        var sTheam = filterContext.HttpContext.Items["Theam"].ToString();

        HttpCookie theamCookie = new HttpCookie("TheamCookie");

        theamCookie.Values.Add("TheamVal", sTheam);
        theamCookie.Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(5);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(theamCookie);
    }
}
```

No mater what I do the cookie is not persisted. Only when replace sTheam to a value like "cupid" the value is persisted. That is

```
theamCookie.Values.Add("TheamVal", "cupid");
```

works and nothing else.

Can any one throw some light as to what is happening? I am exhausted, and completely ran out of options. After over 8 hours of debugging that I realized this. But not sure why is this happening. Please help.

Update: The following is the CookieFilter. This is an ASP.NET MVC app.

```
public class CookieFilter : IActionFilter
{
    //private const string sTheamCookieName = "TheamCookie";
    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.Items["TheamToBrowser"] != null)
        {
            var sTheam = ((string)(filterContext.HttpContext.Items["TheamToBrowser"])).ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

            HttpCookie theamCookie = new HttpCookie("TheamCookie");


            theamCookie.Values["TheamVal"] = "shamrock";
            theamCookie.Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(5);
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Add(theamCookie);
        }
    }

    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        HttpContextBase context = filterContext.HttpContext;
        HttpCookie theamCookie = context.Request.Cookies["TheamCookie"];

        if (theamCookie == null)
            context.Items["TheamFromBrowser"] = "default";
        else
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(theamCookie.Value))
            {
                context.Items["TheamFromBrowser"] = "default";
            }
            else
                context.Items["TheamFromBrowser"] = theamCookie.Values["TheamVal"].ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens if you add your cookie this way `Response.Cookies.Add(theamCookie);` also how is this value declared ..? `TheamCookie`is it a const string.. perhaps this is being set to string.Empty somewhere..

Comment: filterContext.HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(theamCookie)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6227222/how-do-i-add-a-cookie-for-every-visitor-to-my-asp-net-mvc-site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding this line:

```
if (filterContext.HttpContext.Items["Theam"] != null)
```

`HttpContext.Items` is a request-level setting. That means you need to reload it on every HTTP request. If you are not setting `HttpContext.Items["Theam"]` somewhere in the request lifecycle before this piece of code is run, it will always be empty.

I am not sure that is your problem, but it would explain why the rest of your code is working when you set the variable manually.

Comment: I found the problem. First I thank every one for your time. The problem is I am using an ajax call. This ajax call does makes a call to the action method at the server. The request goes from the action filter's OnActionExecutING to the ActionMethod in the controller and then back to the OnActionExecutED. Every thing happen fine till this point. But because this is an ajax call some thing happens after this and cookies are not set. So do not set cookies via an ajax call. See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8908345/unable-to-update-cookie-in-asp-net Now I use '@Url.Action("SetTheam")'.