# Inserting values into cookies when logging in

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cookies

I would like to ask you how I can add custom values into cookies when logging to my ASP.NET MVC application.

In my database I have got three tables. One is Users which in I have got UserId, UserName and Password columns. 
I have also got two other tables: Employees and Offices. 
In Employees table I have got columns like: EmployeeId, UserId, OfficeId, EmployeeName, EmployeeSurname.

I use my custom membership provider in application and EntityFramework. I want to add to cookies when logging values EmployeeId and OfficeId depending on UserId value. Then I want to receive those values when showing GridView to custom user.

Thank you very kindly for replies.

Best Regards.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3147323/cookie-management-in-mvc

Answer (score 0):

> Use this for storing HttpCookie aCookie = new
>   HttpCookie("userInfo");  aCookie.Values["EmployeeId"] =
>   model.EmployeeId;  aCookie.Values["OfficeId"] = model.OfficeId; 
>   aCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(365); 
>   Response.Cookies.Add(aCookie);
>
> check like this
>
> if (Request.Cookies["userInfo"] != null)
>                   {
>                       mdl.EmployeeId =
>   Server.HtmlEncode(Request.Cookies["userInfo"]["EmployeeId"]);
>                       mdl.OfficeId =
>   Server.HtmlEncode(Request.Cookies["userInfo"]["OfficeId"]);
>
> ```
>             }
> ```